# Controller test with RSPEC and FactoryGirl fails with error expected: 1 got: 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

The model `Organization` has many `Events` and and `Event` always belongs to an `Organization`.

My `Events controller` test, the file `controllers/events_controller_spec.rb` is:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe EventsController, type: :controller do

  describe "POST #create" do
    context "with valid attributes" do
      it "create new event" do
        post :create, event: attributes_for(:event)
        expect(Event.count).to eq(1)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

This is my `factories/organizations.rb` file:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :organization do
    organization_name { Faker::Company.name }
  end

  factory :invalid_organization, class: Organization do
    organization_name ''
  end
end
```

This is my `factories/events.rb`file:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    event_description { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3) }
    host_name { Faker::Internet.domain_name }
    organization { create(:organization) }
  end
end
```

Based on the above I am assuming that an `organization` is created before any  `event` is created.

My test is failing with this error.

```
$ rspec spec/controllers/events_controller_spec.rb

Failures:

  1) EventsController POST #create with valid attributes create new event
     Failure/Error: expect(Event.count).to eq(1)

       expected: 1
            got: 0

       (compared using ==)
     # ./spec/controllers/events_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.53 seconds (files took 9.03 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure
```

Don't know how to fix it and have the test passed?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the it inside the expect

```
it "create new event" do
  expect do
    post :create, { event: attributes_for(:event) }
  end.to change(Event, :count).by(1)
end
```

Comment: Now I am getting this: Failures:

  1) EventsController POST #create with valid attributes create new event
     Failure/Error: expect(post :create, { event: attributes_for(:event) }).to change(Event, :count).by(1)
       expected #count to have changed by 1, but was not given a block
     # ./spec/controllers/events_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: Now the error seems to be the same: Failures:

  1) EventsController POST #create with valid attributes create new event
     Failure/Error:
       expect do
         post :create, { event: attributes_for(:event) }
       end.to change(Event, :count).by(1)
     
       expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/events_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: Can be something like organization even if is created during an event creation, the organization_id for the event is not passed and new event record creation is rejected? Can't figure out any other reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
it "create new event" do
  event_attributes = FactoryGirl.build(:event).attributes.symbolize_keys 
  post :create, event: event_attributes
  expect(Event.count).to eq(1)
end
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is `attributes_for(:event)` is including an attribute `organization` which is an `Organization` object.  This is NOT what the controller method expects to receive from the `new` form and the event_params and the event is not being created.

Change it so that the fabricated attribute is just the id...

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event do
    event_description { Faker::Lorem.sentence(3) }
    host_name { Faker::Internet.domain_name }
    organization_id { create(:organization).id }
  end
end
```